# Hamiltonian, symplectic transformation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hamilton-equations

I am trying to understand symplectic transformations. Assume that $H(q,p)$ is a Hamiltonian and the corresponding Hamiltonian equations are given as,

\begin{cases}
 \dot q = \dfrac{\partial H}{\partial q}, \\[2ex]
 \dot p = -\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial p}.
\end{cases}

Now lets assume that $z = [p;q]$ then

\begin{split} \dot z = \mathbb{J}\frac{\partial H}{\partial z}, \qquad \mathbb{J}= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & I \\ -I & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{split}

Now let $\phi$ be a transformation such that $\tilde z = \phi(z)$. Then
\begin{split} \dot{\tilde z} = \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial z} \dot z = \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial z} \mathbb{J}\frac{\partial H}{\partial z}\stackrel{?}{=} \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial z} \mathbb{J} \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial z}^T \frac{\partial H}{\partial \tilde z}. \end{split}

I do not fully understand the final step in the previous equation. If that step is correct then obviously $\phi$ is symplectic if and only if 
\begin{split} \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial z} \mathbb{J} \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial z}^T =  \mathbb{J}. \end{split}

How can we know that $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial z}^T \frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde z}$ when only thing we know is $\tilde z = \phi(z)$?

Answer (score 3):

It's just the chain rule. To avoid confusion, write $H(z) = G(\tilde{z}) = G(\phi(z))$.
Then
$$
\frac{\partial H}{\partial z_k}(z) = \sum_i \frac{\partial G}{\partial \tilde{z}_i}(\phi(z)) \, \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial z_k}(z)
.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems so simple now.

Comment: can you help me with an answer regarding the transpose. I don't know from where appears that "T" in the equation: 
\begin{split} \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial z} \mathbb{J} \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial z}^T =  \mathbb{J} \end{split}
thanks!

Comment: @luli: It's because the last factor is $\partial \phi_i/\partial z_k$ and not $\partial \phi_k/\partial z_i$ (which is what you would get without transposing).

Comment: @HansLundmark I have one more question. I think I don't understand very well what is about the transpose of the jacobian. I want to ask you if you can follow the following link: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/dynamics/clas.pdf (page 100). Why  the relation (4.93) and (4.94) are equivalent?  In equation (4.93) $\frac{\partial H}{\partial y_l}$ has't same range with the others terms in that equation and the matrix product shouldn't be possible. In equation (4.94) it is a rearrangement. Why this is possible? Because the product of matrix is not commutative.. How does the transpose appear?

Comment: @luli: In (4.93), you can rearrange, because there it's just multiplication of *numbers*. And if you swap the last two factors there, you get something which is clearly equal to the matrix product (4.94) (just use the definition of matrix product, $(AB)_{ij} = \sum_k A_{ik} B_{kj}$).